# Redhat in VMware - adding second VNIC set up with NAT for SSH

Tags: networking, ssh, virtualbox, vmware, nat

I have had a questioned answered on a issue I was having with Hamachi VPN and connecting it to my Linux VM to use a tunnel for SSH outside my local home network. The person that answered the question led me to a VMWare KB about NAT and looks like I can access the VM external using NAT. I have very little knowledge in setting up NAT on VM and was hoping there is an KB or DIY somewhere that would tell me more on how to set this up. My network my VM is on is set up on a Win 2008 Enterprise server with VMWare 10 running the RedHat VM. Do I have to config my router for a NAT tunnel?

Sorry if this question is silly, I am programmer not a systems guy too much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hamachi will only allow you to connect to services running on the PC you are running the Hamachi client on.

the exact details on how to set up NAT will vary based on your router, firewall and ISP, however specific details can be found on http://portforward.com/english/routers/port_forwarding/